# How is a Meteor user altered when copying from an existing mongo meteor db

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a Meteor app running locally and on a vm (changes to local are pushed to vm) so the code is always the same between them. The app on the vm uses a mongodb instance located on the vm, whereas my local app uses a local mongodb instance (I can of course use the remote mongodb instance locally, but I don't want to risk messing it up when developing).

I had an issue with my local mongodb so I dropped the db entirely, dumped the remote db and restored it locally, so in essence the two dbs are now identical again.

When I log in locally, however, the app doesn't work as expected. It allows me to login with my original user/password combo but publications that were previously available are now no longer being published.

If I run my local app using the local db, login and then view my user ID using Mongol I get an id like `ZmW62ZqEQXjXGzc9Q`, but if I restart the app using the remote db, login with the same user details I now get `q6drPCkwcRuhL72RF` as a user ID. So clearly, this 'change' in user when copying the db is the cause for publications not being available.

Could someone please explain why this happened, and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

The _id of MongoDB is normally a 12-byte BSON type containing:

> [(from the MongoDb documentation)](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

While the default type for Meteor's MongoDB is a random string ([see the documentation here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)).

I assume you are creating the user via a fixture (?), so when your app creates a new user, Meteor assigns to it a random id. Now, when you login, Meteor checks for a combination of user/password which are unchanged, but then it sends back the id (which has changed, being generated as a random string).

To get around it you could `meteor reset` your app (it will erase the local db).

Comment: I tried `meteor reset` but that didn't help. I have noticed that it is indeed the fixtures file in my app creating (or re-creating the users) despite the fact they exist in the db. So if I meteor reset, remove the fixtures and start the app I can no longer login, but if I look in the mongo users db directly I can see the users are there